# send latest location to the Firestore even when the app is terminated using carp_background_location

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to send the latest location update received from carp_background_location to Firestore. The callback doesn't get excuted when the app is terminated on Android. I haven't tried if it works on iOS yet.

I'm following this example provided by the package:
[example](https://pub.dev/packages/carp_background_location/example)

What I want is to use this callback to send location to Firestore:

```
void onData(LocationDto dto) {
    // print(dtoToString(dto));
    print(dto);
    setState(() {
      lastLocation = dto;
      lastTimeLocation = DateTime.now();
    });
    pushDtoToFirebase()

  }
```

this works fine in the foreground or the background but not when the app is terminated.

I'd really appreciate a solution to the problem or guidance on how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch take a look at this, this should solve your issue

Comment: Should I start listening to the stream in the background or do periodic fetches of location using this plugin? I haven’t understood the approach yet.. please clarify

Comment: i personally prefer periodic fetching of location.